# iPad app - Drawing objects on the screen one at a time

Tags: ios, ipad

What is the best way to go about making an app that does the following: the user taps at locations, and on the locations, a square is drawn. There is no way to erase the squares. You simply tap wherever you want and squares of a predefined size are drawn.

I was thinking to make a custom UIView and override the drawRect method by keeping a list of all the (x,y) locations of the squares and then calling [customView setNeedsDisplay] and drawing all the squares everytime a new square is drawn.

Is there a better way?

In Java, I would use an offscreen image, draw the square onto the offscreen image, and then draw the image onto the screen on every repaint() call. But, is this good to do for iPad? If so, what is code that will let me initialize a UIImage and draw a square onto it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just add an empty `UIView`, which you only set the background color on, and then add it to the view you are tapping.

Example of adding a yellow square in the viewcontroller's `viewDidLoad`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIView *square = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 30, 30, 30)];
    square.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];

    [self.view addSubview:square];

    [square release];
}
```

Note: You can also give each square an id in its `tag` and later retrieve them with `viewWithTag:` from their superview (i.e. `self.view` from the controller)

Comment: and then when/where do I draw the squres?

Comment: @CodeGuy they are drawn automatically after you added them to the view.

Comment: how do you add a square to a view?

Comment: addSubview automatically draws the square and adds it to the view for you.

Comment: but what is the subview I pass to addSubview? Do I make a custom UIView that's a square?

Comment: @CodeGuy try my example, just to get a square you can use a plain `UIView`, don't need to subclass it. Just set its `backgroundColor`